# Como abrir uma ImageView em tela cheia usando OnClickListener?

Tags: java, android, android-layout

Eu tenho um aplicativo e gostaria de exibir uma imagem em tela cheia. A captura de tela abaixo mostra um exemplo de aplicativo.

Como eu poderia colocar ela em tela cheia, usando onClickListener?

E como eu poderia fazer a mesma coisa usando intents para um aplicativo padrão de fotos do celular?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O resultado esperado seria algo mais ou menos assim:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: https://developer.android.com/training/animation/zoom.html